# Is it problematic for stomach/guts to skip breakfast?

Tags: nutrition, stomach, physical-health, meal

In [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/breakfast-lose-weight) we read

> Many people skip the a.m. meal because they’re rushing to get out the door. That’s a mistake. You need food in your system long before
> lunchtime.

However I have come across [this article](https://blogs.bmj.com/bmj/2019/01/30/tim-spector-breakfast-the-most-important-meal-of-the-day/) that says

> The disadvantages of skipping breakfast have now been debunked by several randomised trials. A systematic review and meta-analysis of the 11 randomised trials of skipping breakfast performed to date is published today in this journal. The studies varied widely in duration and quality, and seven looked at changes in weight as well as changes in energy usage. The conclusions were the same as in recent, largely ignored qualitative reviews namely, that no evidence supports the claim that skipping breakfast makes you gain weight or adversely reduces your resting metabolic rate.

There seems to be various opinions on the importance of eating breakfast, however, I wonder if there's any long term problem in the stomach/guts associated with skipping breakfast?

Comment: "Is breakfast the most important?" isn't a question that is answerable scientifically. A question like "does skipping breakfast result in (weight gain/reduced performance on XYZ/some specific negative health outcome?" is. You'll get a better answer if you update to something like the latter.

Comment: What matters is the total amount of nutrients you consume, not when.

Comment: There are two problems with this question. First, as @BryanKrause points out, it's opinion-based as currently stated. You could fix that by editing as he suggests, but then the question is still about diet and nutrition, and those subjects are specifically off topic unless they're directly connected to medical treatments. I'm afraid the question just isn't a good fit for this site.

Comment: @CareyGregory I think it would be okay if it lost the opinion bit ("most important") and substituted a specific medical outcome (say, "blood sugar in diabetics", or even "weight change among obese") rather than effectively asking "what/when should I/other people eat?" like most of the diet/nutrition questions are, or addressing a non-medical outcome like physical strength. https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1014/8728 is my meta opinion on that, though of course if there is discussion to happen it should happen there on Meta.

Comment: Okay, that seems reasonable. If OP or someone else wants to edit the question to ask about a specific medical outcome from eating/not eating breakfast, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: [See here](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-20243692): "Breakfast as we know it didn't exist for large parts of history. The Romans didn't really eat it, usually consuming only one meal a day around noon, says food historian Caroline Yeldham. In fact, breakfast was actively frowned upon.

"The Romans believed it was healthier to eat only one meal a day," she says. "They were obsessed with digestion and eating more than one meal was considered a form of gluttony. This thinking impacted on the way people ate for a very long time.""

Comment: In India there is an ancient phrase: "One who eats thrice a day is rogi (diseased), twice is a bhogi (food enjoyer), once the Yogi". Am eating only two meals a day with only a tea in between. All this in 8-10 hours window and rest of the time, I will just have a water. Am doing this since child hood, that is more than a decade. Now I realise its called intermittent fasting in West!! In the morning, after bowel movements, I take glass full of water and dont eat anything for an hour. This again cleanses system. Then I have a lunch @ 2PM, after lunch I have a tea @ 7PM and dinner @ 10PM.